# The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver; IllegalStateException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, illegalstateexception

I have 2 packages. In one package I have declared the `launchBrowser()` method which looks like this:

```
package BaseCode;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

        public void launchBrowser(String baseUrl) throws Exception{
            try {
                    System.out.println("Launching the Chrome Browser");
                    String driverpath = "E:\\Learning\\Selenium\\Drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe";
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverpath);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    System.out.println("Opening URL: " + baseUrl);
                    driver.get(baseUrl);
        }catch(Exception E) {
            System.out.println(E.getMessage() +"\n" + E.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
}
```

The second class where I am calling the above `launchBrowser()` method is this:

```
package pack_one;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import BaseCode.TestBase;

public class MultipleiFrames {

    public static TestBase B = new TestBase();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String url = "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/";
        try {
            B.launchBrowser(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

When running the code I am getting **Exception** in thread "main":

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable
>   must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property

Please help me....

Comment: Please format your question appropriately, including the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am first time to this forum so didn't know. I will keep that in mind from next time.

Comment: It's ok, just make sure you read through these topics :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're initialising the chromedriver twice, once at the start of the second class you posted, and then again in the launchBroswer method when you call that within the second class. As you're setting the chromedriver path within the launchBrowser method, the first call to initialise chromeDriver won't have that property set

Comment: Got it !! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a general issue make sure that you have to initialize class only once otherwise this exception occurs.

Just remove one declaration of initialization of driver, rest is fine

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```